# Transloadit: Sending 0 byte file while request.body.read is not empty

Tags: ruby, ajax, upload, sinatra, xmlhttprequest

I'm using transloadit and sending files with xhr using valumns file uploader.

Files are sent to the server without errors (i checked size and content of request.body.read) but once I do:

response = assembly.submit! (request.body)

An empty file is sent (I checked many times in the assemblies history page).

Thanks for you help.

Comment: Try: `require 'stringio'; response = assembly.submit!(StringIO.new(request.body.read))`

Comment: Hi, I tried that but didn't work neither. It keeps sending an empty file.

Comment: I have the same problem within rails together with carrierwave. I can write request.body.read to a file, but when I pass it to carrierwave I get: ArgumentError (string contains null byte)

Comment: @huug try send sending files less then 100ko to see if we have same issue. When I send files with size > 100ko or so, it works, but when the size is less is doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Call `request.body.rewind` before using `request.body`.

Comment: Thank you @Konstantin Haase,it partially work ! When I send files with size > 100ko or so, it works, but when the size is less is doesn't !

Comment: That is strange, what server are you using?

Comment: Have you checked the request headers? It might be that for small files your uploader does not use multi-part but switches to a regular http post style request.

Comment: - @evaneykelen, I always check response.body.read for both small and large files and data is valid. I also confirm that the uploader always uses xhr no matter what the file size is. Thanks for your help.